# Is there a way to distinct multiple columns in sql?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to distinct multiple columns? When I tried to do it with p.name it says that there is an error that occurred.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( V.NAME ), 
               POH.status, 
               poh.shipdate, 
               pod.orderqty, 
               POD.receivedqty, 
               POD.rejectedqty, 
               p.NAME 
FROM   purchasing.vendor v 
       INNER JOIN purchasing.productvendor pv 
               ON v.businessentityid = pv.businessentityid 
       INNER JOIN production.product p 
               ON pv.productid = P.productid 
       INNER JOIN purchasing.purchaseorderdetail POD 
               ON P.productid = POD.productid 
       INNER JOIN purchasing.purchaseorderheader POH 
               ON POD.purchaseorderid = POH.purchaseorderid 
ORDER  BY v.NAME, 
          p.NAME;
```

Comment: use `group by` in your query it will work's

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Tag your DB/SQL engine

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `NAME`, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with q as (
      <your query here with columns renamed so there are no duplicates>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by v_name order by v_name) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT is not a function, it is an operator and its scope is the entire SELECT clause
(The query formatting is just for emphasizing the point)

```
SELECT     DISTINCT 

           V.NAME, 
           POH.status, 
           poh.shipdate, 
           pod.orderqty, 
           POD.receivedqty, 
           POD.rejectedqty, 
           p.NAME

FROM      purchasing.vendor v

...
```

That answers the error you get, however, I doubt if this will give you the results you are looking for